# Change Visual Assets (Appx Manifest) Images During Runtime Using Other Images In Asset Folder

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am currently developing an app for a public school. With this app, teacher can log in into their class. The school has three classes: science, business and language.

Default visual assets are from the science class. I want to change the app icon, app name, and app splash screen (e.g. from Earth Icon to Dollar or Flag icon), depends on to which class the teacher signs in. These icons are all in the Assets folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to change the visual assets at runrime. But you could make [styles and themes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210949.aspx) for different teachers and use the styles and themes to customize the appearance of your apps.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, I already managed to change the look and feel of the app. But I aim to change the logo and the splash-screen image of the app too. Too bad if it's can't be changed during the runtime